# CircleCI deployments to Heroku fail: SSH Connection timed out

Tags: heroku, circleci

I have a CircleCi deployment that's been working for a few years. I last attempted it March 8 and it worked. But now it's failing on this step.

I've contacted CircleCi about it, and they say it's related to the March 15 GitHub SSH deprecation. I don't see how that's possible. I can't telnet to heroku.com:22 from my local machine, or from any other virtual servers I have access to. If you can't reach the port, it doesn't matter which key you have or don't have, right? It's TCP/IP.

It's definitely curious that the March 15 deprecation occurred between March 8 and 30th, I've gone through this [link](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/4417542273179-GitHub-SSH-Deprecation-Information-Resolutions) and tried regenerating keys, and installing OpenSSH 8.1, they don't seem to have any effect.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
    git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:our-project.git
    ssh-keyscan -H heroku.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    git push heroku master
fi

ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Exited with code exit status 128
CircleCI received exit code 128
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of November 30, 2021, the SSH Git Transport feature has been deprecated by Heroku and only HTTP transport is supported. The real shutdown of SSH was in March 2022.

You have to reconfigure the repo with :

```
heroku git:remote -a <app-name>
```

[Official statement from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2301)

Maybe you will have to unset ssh connections on git global config :

```
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku/.insteadof
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadof
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It looks like the image we are using for CicleCi doesn't have Heroku installed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a few environment variables to CircleCi, creating a `~/.netrc` file and  and switching to HTTP seems to be working:

```
echo "machine git.heroku.com login ${HEROKU_USERNAME} password ${HEROKU_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/our-project.git
```